# Google Api Redirect gives me 404 error on WP7 When using Windows 8 but not Windows 7

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, windows-phone-7, google-api, internet-explorer-10

I been scratching my head trying to figure out why a project I have(what I did not touch) was not working anymore.

Basically I was trying trying to get some data back from google contacts. When I selected "allow" in the oAuth part it would keep giving me a 404 error. This is all done in the windows phone 7 emulator.

I then realized that I was on my Windows 8 partition so I went back to my windows 7 partition and it works.

Wondering if it is some IE 10 issue or something. Anyone have any theories of why this is happening?

**Edit**

Here is some quick sample code I whipped up maybe someone can try it and tell me what is going on.

```
 string clientId = "You client id here";

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            string url = String.Format("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https://www.google.com/m8/feeds&redirect_uri=http://localhost&response_type=code&approval_prompt=auto&client_id={0}", clientId);
            webBrowser1.Navigated += new EventHandler<System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs>(webBrowser1_Navigated);



            webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute));




        }



        void webBrowser1_Navigated(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
           var queryParmas = e.Uri.ParseQueryString();

           foreach (var item in queryParmas)
           {
               if (item.Key == "code")
               {
                   string test1 = "If you got here then it works";
                   string test2 = "in windows 8";

               }
           }
        }


    }
```

xaml

```
 <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <phone:WebBrowser HorizontalAlignment="Left" IsScriptEnabled="True" Name="webBrowser1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="669" Width="468" />
        </Grid>
```

**Edit2**

They released IE 10 for Windows 7 so I installed that and it still works on Windows 7 so I guess it is not an IE issue. Must be something with Windows 8? Maybe iis?

**Edit3**

Here is a flow of what is happening in Windows 7

1. Application start up and loads MainPg.xmal
2. Navigated is triggered but if statement is skipped
3. User Sees Google Login Page and enters in information and hits login
4. Navigated is triggered but if statement is skipped
5. User sees "request page" and must allow application permissions
6. User hit allow
7. Navigated is triggered and goes into "if" statement
8. User sees IIS 7 screen.

Here is a flow of what is happening in Windows 8

1. Application start up and loads MainPg.xmal
2. Navigated is triggered but if statement is skipped
3. User Sees Google Login Page and enters in information and hits login
4. Navigated is triggered but if statement is skipped
5. User sees "request page" and must allow application permissions
6. User hit allow
7. Goes to 404 pages Navigated is not triggered.

As you can see it goes all wrong after the allow button is pressed. In windows 7 it goes back to the Navigated method and then shows IIS 7 welcome page but in Windows 8 after the allow button is hit it does not go to the navigated page and shows 404 instead.

Comment: what exactly did you swap to your win7 partition?

Comment: I don't know what you mean? I have dual boot windows 8 and windows 7. I have windows 7 phone sdk and VS 2010 installed on both. If I take the same project and run it in Windows 8 it does not work. If I run it in windows 7 it works.

Comment: Thanks, that was what I wanted to know. It wasn't clear to me, weather you just moved some files or run another OS. 
I am totally not aware of what you doing there exactly, but the 'localhost' makes me suspicious if you are switching OSes.

Comment: I have dual boot. I made the project in Vs2010 on Windows 7. The project works as expected with localhost being the redirect url set as a valid link in Google. I copy the entire folder of my project and put it in windows 8 and run it in Vs2010 that also has windows 7 phone emulator and exactly same sdk and it does not work. Once it tries to redirect it fails.

Comment: Interesting question. If you step through your Win7Phone code in VS2010, at what point is the 404 thrown?

Comment: I have updated my OP to give you a flow but the best thing is to run it yourself and you will see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using the "Navigating" event handler, not the "Navigated" event handler. This will allow you to cancel the navigation when you get the code value. The navigated handler is called after the navigation and since the callback url does not really exist, it throws the 404 error. It seems like it is operating correctly on your Windows 8, not sure why you are not getting the 404 on Windows 7 because you should see it there too.

Comment: I think I tried Navigating as well but I will try it again to double check and you have it reversed. It works on Windows 7 but not on Windows 8.

Comment: What I am saying is that you "should" be getting a 404 error when using the "navigated" event because the event is called after the navigation is complete and the callback url points to an invalid location. The "navigating" event handler will get called before navigating to the callback url so it will give you a chance to parse the url before the navigation, so it will not give the 404 error.

Comment: Hmm weird. Well Navigating seems to give me the code part so that is at least good then I guess from that method I would call a new view instead of letting it redirect to localhost?

Comment: You can set e.Cancel to true to prevent the navigation, then signal your app that the login was successful, or navigate to a new page etc.

Comment: Hmm I am using RestSharp and the code is in a service layer and is async so I have to use callbacks..How do I access e.Cancel after the callback happens? I have 2 call backs one for success(will go to a new page) and one for failures(will do a popup). So not sure if I should just have e.Cancel regardless of outcome